# How to maximize the GCD of n positive integers with minimum number of removals from the sequence that represents them?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, number-theory, greatest-common-divisor

I'm trying to solve a competitive programming task which I cannot find out effective solution to tackle the last 5 test cases with.

You are given with t (t >= 1 && t <= 5) inquiries each of which consists of n numbers num (num >= 1 && num <= 1000000). The sequence that represents each inquiry isn’t sorted and there can be repeating numbers in it. The sum of all ns is less than 1000000. Let's call the GCD of all numbers in a single inquiry x. The task is to find out what is the minimum number of removals that have to be made in order to maximize x. Time limit is 0.7 s.

Consider that this (8, 2, 6, 4, 10, 12) is the inquiry that I’m given. GCD (8, 2, 6, 4, 10, 12) = 2 but If I remove 2, 6 and 10 GCD (8, 4, 12) = 4. I increased initial GCD x from 2 to 4 with 3 removals namely 2, 6 and 10. The answer of this inquiry is 3.

The best ideas I've come up with so far are the following ones:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <numeric>
#include <limits>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main() {
    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cin.tie(nullptr);
    int t;
    std::cin >> t;
    int i, n, tmp, j, num, div, max, min, rem;
    std::vector<int> ans;
    for (i = 0; i != t; ++i) {
        std::cin >> n;
        tmp = 0;
        std::map<int, int> buckets;
        for (j = 0; j != n; ++j) {
            std::cin >> num;
            tmp = std::gcd(tmp, num);
            for (div = 1; div * div <= num; ++div) {
                if (num % div == 0) {
                    ++buckets[div];
                    if (div * div != num) {
                        ++buckets[num / div];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        max = tmp;
        min = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
        for (auto const& elem : buckets) {
            if (elem.second != n && elem.first > max) {
                rem = n - elem.second;
                if (rem < min) {
                    max = elem.first;
                    min = rem;
                }
            }
        }
        ans.emplace_back(min);
    }
    std::copy(ans.cbegin(), std::prev(ans.cend()),
        std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));
    std::cout << ans.back() << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

I’m calculating x (tmp) and splitting each number (num) into its divisors (div). I’m constantly updating buckets which is a std::map<div, count of numbers in the particular inquiry t that this div can divide>. I loop through buckets and find out which is the divisor (elem.first) that is greater than max (x) and at the same time leads to minimum number of removals.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>
#include <limits>

int main() {
    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cin.tie(nullptr);
    int t;
    std::cin >> t;
    int i, n, tmp_gcd, tmp_max, j, num,
        ans, k, tmp_sum, l, tmp_min;
    for (i = 0; i != t; ++i) {
        std::cin >> n;
        std::vector<int> inq_db;
        inq_db.reserve(n);
        tmp_max = tmp_gcd = 0;
        for (j = 0; j != n; ++j) {
            std::cin >> num;
            inq_db.emplace_back(num);
            tmp_gcd = std::gcd(tmp_gcd, num);
            tmp_max = std::max(tmp_max, num);
        }
        std::vector<int> buckets(tmp_max + 1);
        for (auto const& elem : inq_db) {
            ++buckets[elem];
        }
        ans = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
        for (k = tmp_gcd + 1; k <= tmp_max; ++k) {
            tmp_sum = 0;
            for (l = k; l <= tmp_max; l += k) {
                tmp_sum += buckets[l];
            }
            tmp_min = n - tmp_sum;
            if (tmp_min != n && tmp_min < ans) {
                ans = tmp_min;
            }
        }
        std::cout << ans << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I’m calculating x (tmp_gcd) and finding out maximum value of num (tmp_max) in the inquiry t that I’m working with. I initialize buckets with max + 1 zeroes (counters). I do this in order to avoid initializing buckets with 1000000 counters each time. Instead of splitting the number into its divisors I’m using the counters in buckets to count the numbers that are equal to their index. 5th element in buckets is counting how many numbers with the value 5 I have in the inquiry, 100th element – value 100 and so on. I loop through buckets starting from index x + 1 and find out how many numbers with GCD = k I have in buckets. The idea here is that numbers k, 2*k, 3*k, 4*k, 5*k and so on have GCD = k. I find out which is the number (ans) that leads to minimum number of removals.

The problem with both my ideas is that they are given with time limit exceeded on the last 5 test cases. I need some help to optimize them or If this is not possible to be given a new one. Thanks in advance for your time.

@Damien I reworked your logic this way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>

std::vector<int> split(int num) {
    std::vector<int> ret;
    if ((num & 1) == 0) {
        ret.emplace_back(2);
        do {
            num >>= 1;
        } while ((num & 1) == 0);
    }
    int div, div_lim;
    for (div = 3, div_lim = static_cast<int>(std::sqrt(num)); div <= div_lim; div += 2) {
        if (num % div == 0) {
            ret.emplace_back(div);
            do {
                num /= div;
            } while (num % div == 0);
            div_lim = static_cast<int>(std::sqrt(num));
        }
    }
    if (num != 1) {
        ret.emplace_back(num);
    }
    return ret;
}

int main() {
    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cin.tie(nullptr);
    int t;
    std::cin >> t;
    int i, n, x, j, num, ans;
    std::map<int, int>::const_iterator it;
    for (i = 0; i != t; ++i) {
        std::cin >> n;
        std::vector<int> seq;
        seq.reserve(n);
        x = 0;
        for (j = 0; j != n; ++j) {
            std::cin >> num;
            seq.emplace_back(num);
            x = std::gcd(x, num);
        }
        if (x != 1) {
            for (auto& elem : seq) {
                elem /= x;
            }
        }
        std::map<int, int> lookup;
        for (auto const& elem : seq) {
            auto ret = split(elem);
            for (auto const& div : ret) {
                ++lookup[div];
            }
        }
        it = std::max_element(lookup.cbegin(), lookup.cend(),
            [](std::pair<const int, int> const& lhs, std::pair<const int, int> const& rhs) {
                return lhs.second < rhs.second;
            });
        ans = n - it->second;
        std::cout << ans << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but sadly I hit TLE on the last 5 test cases.

@TonyK It is in Bulgarian because the task is given on a Bulgarian competitive programming competition.

If I have this (4 6 8 10 12 14) test GCD is 2. Now let's split each number into its divisors:

4 (1, 2, 4)

6 (1, 2, 3, 6)

8 (1, 2, 4, 8)

10 (1, 2, 5, 10)

12 (1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12)

14 (1, 2, 7, 14)

The candidates for GCD > 2 are the following ones:

14->I have to remove all the numbers but 14->5 removals

12->I have to remove all the numbers but 12->5 removals

10->I have to remove all the numbers but 10->5 removals

8->I have to remove all the numbers but 8->5 removals

7->I have to remove all the numbers but 14->5 removals

6->I have to remove 4, 8, 10 and 14->4 removals

5->I have to remove all the numbers but 10->5 removals

4->I have to remove 6, 10 and 14->3 removals

3->I have to remove 4, 8, 10 and 14->4 removals

The answer is 3 removals and they can be achieved at GCD = 4.

Comment: In the example, if you remove 2, 4, 8, and 10, then you have GCD(6,12) which is 6. And I don't see any rule that prevents you from removing all but the 12, resulting in a GCD of 12.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by *maximising x* ? Increase it?

Comment: As @user3386109 noted, keeping all copies of the largest number and throwing away the rest solves the problem as stated. Did you state it correctly? (Prog comp questions aren't usually "trick questions" like this.)

Comment: @ user3386109 yes that's correct but in the task it's stated that this has to be done with minimum number of removals. If you remove 2, 4, 8 and 10 the GCD of the rest will be 6 with 4 removals. If you remove all but 12 the GCD will be 12 with 5 removals. The answer is 4 because it's achieved with 3 removals only.

Comment: @ Damien Initially x of all the numbers is 2. If I remove 3 of them as in the above-mentioned example x of the rest 2 numbers will become 4. Thus x increases its value from 2 to 4 with 2 removals.

Comment: Oh, so you're just trying to find the minimum number of removals that improves `x`. You aren't trying to maximize `x`.

Comment: I suppose there could be two or more sets that have the same number of elements, but result in different improvements to `x`, and in that case you select the set that improves `x` the most. But if your output is just the size of the set (i.e. the number of removals), then you don't really care about maximizing `x`. All you need is the minimal size of the set that makes any improvement to `x`.

Comment: @ user3386109 yes that's exactly what I meant. I need the size of the set which improves x the most and this size has to be the smallest among all the other ones.

Comment: You are trying to optimize two conflicting criteria at a time. This does not work.

Comment: You say that there are several inquiries. Are they related in any way ?

Comment: @Yves Daoust No. Each inquiry has its own answer.

Comment: Your rewriting of my proposal looks quite fine. Note that I proposed a faster variant, but I guess it is the one that you tested recently.

Comment: Peter, the problem as stated doesn't make sense. If the original problem is in English, please provide a link. If not, please try and translate it as accurately as you can.

Comment: @TonyK I added an extended explanation to my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a rather fast solution.

The first step consists in calculating the global gcd and divide all numbers by it.

The global GCD is now equal to 1.
The problem is now to find the minimum number of removals such that this GC is no longer equal to 1.

For that, we perform the prime decomposition of each number, and find the most frequent prime in them.

The result is the array size minus the number of times this prime is present.

The complexity is dominated by the prime decomposition: `O(n sqrt(m))`, where `m` is the maximum data value.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>
#include <limits>
#include <map>
#include <cmath>

//  For test
void print (const std::vector<int> &v) {
        for (auto &x: v) {
                std::cout << x << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
}

//  Get the prime factors of a number (multiplicity is not important here)

std::vector<int> get_primes (int n) {
    int n_sav = n;
    if (n <= 1) return {};
    std::vector<int> primes;

    if (n % 2 == 0) {
        primes.push_back(2);
        n /= 2;
        while (n%2 == 0) {n /= 2;}
    }
    int max_prime = sqrt(n);
    int p = 3;
    while (p <= max_prime) {
        if (n % p == 0) {
            primes.push_back(p);
            n/= p;
            while (n%p == 0) {n /= p;}
            max_prime = sqrt(n);
        }
        p += 2;
    }
    if (n != 1) {
        primes.push_back(n);
    }
    //std::cout << n_sav << ": ";
    //print (primes);
    return primes;
}


int min_removals (std::vector<int>& numbers) {
    int n = numbers.size();
    if (n == 1) return -1;
    int current_gcd = numbers[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) current_gcd = std::gcd (current_gcd, numbers[i]);
    std::cout << "current GCD = " << current_gcd << "\n";
    if (current_gcd != 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) numbers[i] /= current_gcd;
    }
    std::map<int, int> list_primes;
    for (auto x: numbers) {
        auto primes = get_primes(x);
        for (int i: primes) {
            list_primes[i]++;
        }
    }
    int most_frequent = 0;
    for (const auto& p: list_primes) {
        if (p.second > most_frequent) {
            most_frequent = p.second;
        }
    }
    
    return n - most_frequent;
}

int main() {
    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cin.tie(nullptr);
    int t;
    std::cin >> t;
    while (t--) {
        int n;
        std::cin >> n;
        std::vector<int> numbers (n);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            std::cin >> numbers[i];
        }
        auto ans = min_removals (numbers);
        std::cout << ans << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

With the following variant, the speed is slightly increased by incorporating the prime decomposition in the main function. This avoids some useless data copies. It appears that the gain is not negligeable.

```
int min_removals_new (std::vector<int>& numbers) {
    int n = numbers.size();
    if (n == 1) return -1;
    int current_gcd = numbers[0];
    for (int i = 1; (i < n) && (current_gcd > 1); ++i) current_gcd = std::gcd (current_gcd, numbers[i]);
    if (current_gcd != 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) numbers[i] /= current_gcd;
    }
    std::map<int, int> list_primes;
    
    for (auto x: numbers) {
        if (x == 1) continue;
        if (x % 2 == 0) {
            list_primes[2]++;
            x /= 2;
            while (x%2 == 0) {x /= 2;}
        }
        int max_prime = sqrt(x);
        int p = 3;
        while (p <= max_prime) {
            if (x % p == 0) {
                list_primes[p]++;
                x/= p;
                while (x%p == 0) {x /= p;}
                max_prime = sqrt(x);
            }
            p += 2;
        }
        if (x != 1) {
            list_primes[x]++;
        }
    }
       
    int most_frequent = 0;
    for (const auto& p: list_primes) {
        if (p.second > most_frequent) {
            most_frequent = p.second;
        }
    }
    
    return n - most_frequent;
}
```

Comment: How can you solve a problem that is incompletely specified ?

Comment: @Damien I rewrote your logic for practical purpose and sent it for evaluation but unfortunately it hits TLE again on the last 5 test cases.

Comment: @YvesDaoust it seemed to be completely specified when I read the comments. I agree with user3386109. OP first acknowledged their interpretation, and then repeated an ambiguous formulation...it was also corresponding to my understanding of OP's code. This code is too slow, but supposed to be correct.

Comment: @Damien Yes it it correct but as I said it hits TLE on the last 5 test cases.

Comment: @PetarIvanov What do you mean by *for practical purpose*? What is the max size of `n`? Do you have an idea how far we are from a fast enough solution? (i.e. details on the time spent). Do you have a link so that I could do some tests myself?

Comment: @Damien Here you are: https://arena.infosbg.com/#/catalog/444/problem/1203. This is an online judge for Bulgarian competitive programming competitions only. Btw there's a minor bug in your logic. If I give it this (1 7 1 11 1 7 1) test it outputs 3 (it removes the 1s) which is wrong. The answer is 5 (it has to remove all the 1s and 11) which is achieved by removing this (if (n <= 1) return {1};) line. Thus 1 is not considered prime and the algorithm works as it is supposed. I don't know how to copy my code to show you what I meant by practical purpose. It's not possible in the comment section.

Comment: Yes you are right concerning the bug. I will correct the bug in my code.

Comment: Of course I have some difficulty to read this site! Again, what is the maximum value of `n`?

Comment: @Damien In the task it is written that the sum of all ns is less than 1000000 which means that n0 (which is the n for the first inquiry) + n1 (which is the n for the second inquiry) ... + nt (which is the n for the last inquiry) < 1000000.

Comment: You don't need to keep recreating the list of primes for every `n`, just find the largest `n` in all of the lists, generate a list of primes up to that `sqrt(n)` and then retain that list across all `get_prime(..)` calls (but of course do recalc `max_prime` each time)..

Comment: @RBarryYoung  Effectively, according to some tests with random values, the current code is very near to be fast enough. I don't expect a large gain by memorising the primes, but it could be sufficient effectively. At the time being, I have proposed a new code that avoids some copies and shows a non negligeable improvement. I will wait to see if it is enough.

Comment: @Damien Again TLE on the last 5 test cases.

Comment: With `n = 10^6` and random values, I always get the result in less than 0.4s on my PC...Sorry, without more information on the data input, I can't do more ...

Comment: @Damien It's not because of n alone it is because of t and n. If you have t = 5 and each n = 10^6 you cannot get a result in 0.4s with that logic. What piece of information do you need concerning the data input ?

Comment: The sum of `n` is less than 10^6. So one test with n=10^6 should be significant ... Some gains are possible if they  are many duplicates. I made some tests, but the corresponding solutions do not work well if there are not many duplicates. The problem may be related to a corner case. Having the data used for the tests would be ideal of course ...

Answer (score 2):

I've finally found out the solution which is fast enough (550-600 ms) !

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>
#include <bitset>
#include <unordered_map>

int main() {
    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cin.tie(nullptr);
    int t;
    std::cin >> t;
    int i, n, j, num, lim = 0, max, div, cpy, ans;
    std::vector<int> ns, gcds(t);
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> db(t);
    std::vector<int>::const_iterator it;
    std::pair<decltype(it), decltype(it)> ret;
    for (i = 0; i != t; ++i) {
        std::cin >> n;
        ns.emplace_back(n);
        db[i].reserve(n);
        for (j = 0; j != n; ++j) {
            std::cin >> num;
            db[i].emplace_back(num);
            gcds[i] = std::gcd(gcds[i], num);
            lim = std::max(lim, num);
        }
        if (gcds[i] != 1) {
            for (auto& elem : db[i]) {
                elem /= gcds[i];
            }
        }
        std::sort(db[i].begin(), db[i].end());
    }
    auto primes = std::make_unique<std::bitset<10000000 + 1>>();
    primes->set();
    primes->set(0, false);
    primes->set(1, false);
    for (i = 2; i * i <= lim; ++i) {
        if (primes->test(i)) {
            for (j = i * i; j <= lim; j += i) {
                primes->set(j, false);
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i != t; ++i) {
        std::unordered_map<int, int> lookup;
        max = 0;
        for (it = db[i].cbegin(); it != db[i].cend(); it = ret.second) {
            ret = std::equal_range(it, db[i].cend(), *it);
            if (primes->test(*it)) {
                lookup[*it] += ret.second - ret.first;
                if (lookup[*it] > max) {
                    max = lookup[*it];
                }
                continue;
            }
            for (div = 2, cpy = *it; div * div <= cpy; ++div) {
                if (cpy % div == 0) {
                    lookup[div] += ret.second - ret.first;
                    if (lookup[div] > max) {
                        max = lookup[div];
                    }
                    do {
                        cpy /= div;
                    } while (cpy % div == 0);
                }
            }
            if (cpy != 1) {
                lookup[cpy] += ret.second - ret.first;
                if (lookup[cpy] > max) {
                    max = lookup[cpy];
                }
            }
        }
        ans = ns[i] - max;
        std::cout << ans << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I read all the t inquiries and store their nums in a big vector of t vectors each of which consisting of n elements. While reading and storing the nums in db[i] I'm storing each n in the vector ns, calculating the gcd of the particular inquiry gcds[i] and finding out the maximum num lim. When I finish with the reading phase I divide all the nums in db[i] into gcds[i] in order to exclude gcds[i] from the final calculation. I sort db[i] in order to avoid prime decomposition of the repeated nums in it. Based on lim I find out all the prime numbers in the range [2; lim] using a bitset which I store on the heap via the unique_ptr primes. I process each inquiry db[i] using the unordered_map lookup. Using a for loop and equal_range algorithm I jump on the nums in db[i] making prime decomposition only of the first from the repeated ones. For example If I have 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 13 17 19 ... ret.first will point to the first 7 and ret.second will point to 13. Since 7 is already a prime (I check this using the bitset primes) I will not decompose it into primes and I will increment its counter ret.second - ret.first times and compare that counter with max which represents the count of the most frequent num in db[i]. If needed I update max by assignment. In case *it is not prime I will make prime decomposition of it using the next for loop with div and cpy. If I come across to a number like 6 which cannot be fully decomposed using the first for loop I will use the If clause after it because the first iteration will find out 2 as one of the prime factors of 6 and then we will fall through with 3 which has to increment its counter. That's the purpose of the if clause. When I find out which is the most frequent num in db[i] I simply subtract its count from ns[i] and thus find out ans which is the minimum number of removals that have to be made in order to improve gcds[i] the most. I output ans and that's it.